# Apply GPUImage filter to a UIView

Tags: ios, filter, effect, gpuimage

I've a problem. I need to apply a filter like `Pixelate or Blur` to an entire `UIView`.
Like the `eBay iPad` app.

I thought to use `GPUImage` but I don't know how to do it.
There is a way to apply a filter to a `GPUImageView` directly without pass a `UIImage`?

The primary problem is that making a screenshot of a large `UIView` on an `iPad` 3rd is to expensive (2 seconds for the `UIWindow` grab). So the perfect solution is to apply filter directly to the views, just like eBay app, but.. how?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To pull a view into GPUImage, you can use a GPUImageUIElement source, which takes a UIView or CALayer as input. There's an example of this in the FilterShowcase sample application.

This does rely on the `-renderInContext:` method of an underlying CALayer, which can be expensive for redrawing the view. However, if the view is static, you just need to use this update once and the resulting image will be cached on the GPU as a texture. Filter actions applied to it after that point will be very fast.

Comment: Thanks! finally I've found the solution with GPUImage!

Comment: Hi Brad, I can't seem to get this working for my View. I've also created a question on StackOverflow, would be great if you could give it a look! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18353298/using-gpuimage-to-filter-a-view-live

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to achieve the look you are after by applying `CIFilter`s to your views `layer.filters` property. Check the docs for more info:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: but the documentation says: This property is not supported on layers in iOS.

Comment: That definitely was the case, but it was implemented as of iOS5 as I recall. If I look at my current doc set it says: "This property relies on the presence of Core Image and its filters. In iOS, Core Image is available in iOS 5 and later only."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is something for you? Haven't tried it but read about it in a post once:

[StackBlur](https://github.com/tomsoft1/StackBluriOS)

Ow sorry, I read your post again and this extension is about blurring an UIImage, and you said that this was something you didn't want...
Well I'll leave it here anyways if people go googling for blurring an image..
Sorry :(